# How to deal with a dishwasher height issue without tearing out cabinetry when installing flooring?

Tags: flooring, kitchens, dishwasher

The house I purchased has nice new cabinetry and counter tops but cheap flooring.  We plan to install 3/4" wood flooring (already purchased) but learned that installing the flooring would make it so we can't get our dishwasher out, if it were to leak or fail (the legs of the dishwasher are almost all the way up).  It seems that we would need to remove the cabinetry and raise it to solve this problem.  But how well will the cabinetry go back together and can the counter tops (granite) be salvaged? I imagine it won't go back together just as it was.  Are there better ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Pictures are always helpful.

Comment: What kind of counter top? Cabinets come out easy, and it's the only right way to do it.

Comment: The counter top material is granite

Answer (score 2):

Can you keep a section of wood flooring separate in front of the dishwasher? Or, if the floor boards will be parallel to the front of the dishwasher, you would just have to remove a few of those to get the dishwasher out. ( Keep extra floor boards in case you damage the originals and need to replace them?)

Just an idea.

(Never done this or seen it done.)

Comment: Seen this work successfully in an old student flat I lived in. Two sections had the tongue removed so they could be pried up. They were tight enough they didn't move in normal usage.

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to be easy. Because you have Granite, you run a risk of breaking it when you remove it. If you must remove it, I would try to get an installer that would assume responsibility of the removal and re-installation.

Can the dishwasher be relocated? Perhaps in an island? A base cabinet can be added to where the dishwasher was.